# Ajax works sometimes and sometimes not.. Why So?

Tags: jquery, python-3.x, ajax, django-rest-framework, xmlhttprequest

I have saw many similar questions for this but yet I haven't found any clear solution that how to overcome with this.

I have django rest api hosted on pythonanywhere and calling the api to my HTML template that having the following Ajax code.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.sodmzs').click(function(){
                var directory = $("#directory").val();
                var name = $("#name").val();
                var mailing_name = $("#mailing_name").val();
                var address = $("#address").val();

                $.ajax({
                    url : "https://nexerp.pythonanywhere.com/api/create_student",
                    type : "POST",
                    dataType : "json",
                    data : {directory: directory, name : name, mailing_name: mailing_name, address: address}
                })
                .done(function(response){
                    console.log("success");
                })
                .fail(function(){
                    console.log("fail");
                })
                .always(function(){
                    console.log("always");
                })
            });
        </script>
```

I thought it would be CORS issue so I did the following changing in settings.py,

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ....
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ''... ]
```

And is how the create function looks like in views.py,

```
@api_view(['POST',])
def student_create(request):
    account = User.objects.get(pk=1)
    print(account)
    studentobject = Student(author=account)
    if request.method == "POST":
        serializer = StudentSerializer(studentobject, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

my code in models.py,

```
class Student(models.Model):
    student_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    directory = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mailing_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

and my code in serializer.py,

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('student_id','directory','name','mailing_name','address')
```

I literally not having any idea that why it's not working! Out of 10 times, it works just 1 or 2 times. PLease let me know where I'm wrong here.
Thanks.

Comment: What specifically isn't working? What does happen? Need more debugging details. Start with is event working, is request made etc

Comment: @charlietfl When I see the list of students using the type 'GET', I can see the entry in access.log file like this `103.78.137.42 - - [29/Aug/2020:19:23:16 +0000] "GET /api/student/ HTTP/1.1" 500 16775 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36" "103.78.137.42" response-time=0.122` but when I create a student using type 'POST', it doesn't show any entry usually. (sometimes shows, sometimes doesn't).

Comment: So the 500 means server side error. Afraid I'm not a django dev but I'm sure your server side error logs can shed some clues on what issue is